# when i am running my script in compatibility mode i am getting following error?

Tags: internet-explorer-10, autoit

i want to automate the automatic web login this code work with ie9 and for some of the forms(which are developed by using form tag) fine.but when i run same script for the form which is build with tag table it is not taking id's in Ie10, windows8 but the same script take ids with IE9 windows7 but in my work environment now we have mostly windows8 machines. So i came to know to if we run in  compatibility mode we can solve issue when i added code for running in  compatibility  mode i am getting this error . i don't understand what to do..

```
#include <IE.au3>
    #include <GuiButton.au3>
    #include <File.au3>
    #RequireAdmin

        If IsAdmin() then
        $64Bit = ""
            If @OSArch = "X64" Then
                $64Bit = "64"
            EndIf
        If StringLeft(RegRead("HKLM" & $64Bit & "\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Version Vector", "IE"), 1) > 8 Then ;Check for version 9 or later


          $wshNetwork = ObjCreate("WScript.Network")
          $struser = $wshNetwork.Username
          $objWMIService = ObjGet("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
          $objAcc = $objWMIService.Get('Win32_UserAccount.Name="' & $struser & '",Domain="' & @ComputerName & '"')
          $objAccount = $objAcc.SID
          RegWrite("HKU" & $64Bit & "\" & $objAccount & "\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\BrowserEmulation\", "AllSitesCompatibilityMode", "REG_DWORD", 1)
          RegWrite("HKU\" & $objAccount & "\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\BrowserEmulation\", "AllSitesCompatibilityMode", "REG_DWORD", 1)
        EndIf
        EndIf

    $url = "https://190.198.14.15/"
    $formID = ""
    $formUID = "username"
    $uName = "admin"
    $formPID = "password"
    $pwd = "SeR^ER@iL0"
    $formSubmit = "ID_LOGON"

    ;Launch the Internet Explorer as a private session
    ShellExecute ("iexplore.exe", " -private about:blank", @programFilesDir & "\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe", "open", @SW_MAXIMIZE)
    WinWait ("Blank Page")
    $oIE = _IEAttach ("about:blank", "url")

    ;Wait for the IE to launch
    _IELoadWait ($oIE)

    ;Navigate to the given URL
    _IENavigate ($oIE, $url)

    ;Get the IE process id specific to this instance
    Local $PID = WinGetProcess(_IEPropertyGet($oIE, "hwnd"))

    ;Print the PID in the console
    If $PID Then
        ;MsgBox(0, "Example", "Internet Explorer is running.")
        ;MsgBox(0,"Process ID",$PID)
        ConsoleWrite("["&$PID&"]")
    Else
        MsgBox(0, "Example", "Unable to get the process id of IE instance")
    EndIf

    ;Disable IE address bar and menu bar
    _IEPropertySet ($oIE, "addressbar", False)
    _IEPropertySet ($oIE, "menubar", False)

    ;Click on 'Continue to this website' option if there is any HTTPS certificate Warning
    while(_IELinkClickByText ($oIE, "Continue to this website (not recommended)."))
            _IELoadWait ($oIE,10000)
    wend

    ;Get the field id and fill with provided value
    ;$oIE.document.getElementById($formUID).value = $uName
    $oIE.document.getElementsByName($formUID).Item(0).value = $uName
    $oIE.document.getElementById($formPID).value = $pwd

    ;$oSubmit = _IEGetObjByName ($oIE, $formSubmit)
    $oSubmit = $oIE.document.getElementById($formSubmit)
    _IEAction ($oSubmit, "click")
```

when i am running this i am getting an error :

```
>"C:\Program Files (x86)\AutoIt3\SciTE\..\autoit3.exe" /ErrorStdOut "D:\My_Files\Automation scripts\My tests\AutomaticWebpageLogin -1.au3"    
"D:\My_Files\Automation scripts\My tests\AutomaticWebpageLogin -1.au3" (18) : ==> Variable must be of type "Object".:
$objAccount = $objAcc.SID
$objAccount = $objAcc^ ERROR
>Exit code: 1    Time: 0.697
```

Comment: Looking at where it's failing, surely the whole IE automation code is irrelevant as it never reaches it. If you try [this code](http://pastie.org/9201915) on it's own then does it work? Having an example that makes permanent registry changes to peoples computers is not ideal as well, you should at least warn people first.

Comment: my intension was not to change registry setting in some forum i read that if we registry changes then IE compatibility mode will changes .My actuall problem is th above code without registry changes is working fine with IE9 in windows 7 but not working with IE10 windows 8

Comment: Ok, but looking at the error message you are getting, the specific problem is getting the user SID using WMI. All the stuff about IE is not actually relevant to the error you are getting. The next step in debugging is to check the values of variables like `$struser` after you get them from WMI, and trying to see where the problem is. Since this code is working fine for me (as far as I can tell) in windows 8 with IE11, I can't really help you other than saying the error message means you should be directing your efforts to those 5 lines concerning WMI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Error occured at your Authentification process (line of `$objAcc =`), maybe wrong password or username.

Maybe if an error occures, the .Get Function of the WMI Service don't returns an object.

Check for Errors like this

```
if(@error <> 0) Then
  ; ERROR HANDLER
EndIf
```

And check if the account informations are correct.
*[Look at your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23830280/autoit-script-is-not-taking-id-values-from-html-pages-when-i-am-using-ie10-windo)*

**Reference to [Win32_UserAccount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394507%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)**