# Autoit script is not taking id values from html pages when i am using IE10 windows8?

Tags: internet-explorer-10, autoit

The following code takes values from html code in Ie9 but when run same script in Ie10 windows8 it not taking Id values and filling text boxes..here is my script

```
$url = "https://190.198.14.15/"
$formID = ""
$formUID = "username"
$uName = "admin"
$formPID = "password"
$pwd = "SeR^ER@iL0"
$formSubmit = "ID_LOGON"

;Launch the Internet Explorer as a private session
ShellExecute ("iexplore.exe", " -private about:blank", @programFilesDir & "\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe", "open", @SW_MAXIMIZE)
WinWait ("Blank Page")
$oIE = _IEAttach ("about:blank", "url")

;Wait for the IE to launch
_IELoadWait ($oIE)

;Navigate to the given URL
_IENavigate ($oIE, $url)

;Get the IE process id specific to this instance
Local $PID = WinGetProcess(_IEPropertyGet($oIE, "hwnd"))

;Print the PID in the console
If $PID Then
    ;MsgBox(0, "Example", "Internet Explorer is running.")
    ;MsgBox(0,"Process ID",$PID)
    ConsoleWrite("["&$PID&"]")
Else
    MsgBox(0, "Example", "Unable to get the process id of IE instance")
EndIf

;Disable IE address bar and menu bar
_IEPropertySet ($oIE, "addressbar", False)
_IEPropertySet ($oIE, "menubar", False)

;Click on 'Continue to this website' option if there is any HTTPS certificate Warning
while(_IELinkClickByText ($oIE, "Continue to this website (not recommended)."))
        _IELoadWait ($oIE,10000)
wend

;Get the field id and fill with provided value
;$oIE.document.getElementById($formUID).value = $uName
$oIE.document.getElementsByName($formUID).Item(0).value = $uName
$oIE.document.getElementById($formPID).value = $pwd

;$oSubmit = _IEGetObjByName ($oIE, $formSubmit)
$oSubmit = $oIE.document.getElementById($formSubmit)
_IEAction ($oSubmit, "click")
```

here is my html code:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="login_fields_lable" style="width: 34%;">
                <span id="usernameBox" style="white-space: nowrap; vertical-align: middle;" rel="localize[login.LocalUserName]">Local&nbsp;user&nbsp;name:</span>
            </td>

            <td class="login_fields">
                <input autocomplete="off" class="textfield" name="username" id="username" size="30" onkeypress="return checkEnter(event);" type="text">         </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="login_fields_lable" style="width: 34%;">
            <span id="passwordBox" style="vertical-align: middle;" rel="localize[login.password]">Password:</span>
        </td>

        <td class="login_fields">
            <input autocomplete="off" class="textfield" name="password" id="password" size="30" onkeypress="return checkEnter(event);" type="password">
        </td>
        <button id="ID_LOGON" name="ID_LOGON" type="button" onclick="signIn(); return false;" rel="localize[login.loginButton]">Log&nbsp;In</button>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

as html page is designed without form-tag i am facing issue:because of that reason iam using

```
    $oIE.document.getElementById($formUID).value = $uName
$oIE.document.getElementById($formPID).value = $pwd
```

to read id's from html..plz help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use this to get the Element : 
`$oIE.document.getElementById($formUID)`

And The Variable is defined as 
`$formUID = "username"`

But, there is no Input Field or any other element with `id="username"` or `id="password"` in your HTML-Script

change this (line 3 and 5)

```
$formUID = "username"
$formPID = "password"
```

to this

```
$formUID = "usernameInput"
$formPID = "passwordInput"
```

Comment: in html also it is "username and password": $oIE.document.getElementById($formUID) --i am using to read form username id and $oIE.document.getElementById($formUID).value = $uName--through this i am passing value to that particular text box i forgot to make changes in html..while posting

Comment: Did you tried to add an `#` ? Like `$FormUID="#username"`

Comment: Yes. Add this to your html script : `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">` in the header. (If you don't have a valid html file - then you should correct this now). Use `<!DOCTYPE html>`. *[reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536437(v=vs.85).aspx)*

Comment: i can't make any changes to html as it is company website only thing we thing i can do is scripting

Answer (score 0):

1. Open IE
2. Go to "Tools"
3. Go to "Internet Options"
4. Click on "Security" tab
5. Uncheck the "Enable Protected mode" checkbox
6. Restart IE and try your script